# how does the interesting number method work and always come up with 1089

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [a question about permutation in the digits in the decimal system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183661/a-question-about-permutation-in-the-digits-in-the-decimal-system)

I dont get how it works but the method is:

think of a three didgit number with none of the same didgits ; 124
Reverse it ; 421
then take the smallest from the biggest ; 421-124=297
Then reverse your answer ; 792
Then add them together ; 792+297=1089

Now remember that number
then do it again with a different number

867 
768
867-768=099
990
990+99=1089

I dont get how it works

can you find a number that doesn't ???

Comment: See for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183661/a-question-about-permutation-in-the-digits-in-the-decimal-system

Comment: it is so magical ;)

Comment: Now generalize it. What happens if you do the same problem with, say, appropriate four-digit numbers?

Answer (score 5):

Let the digits be $\rm\:abc,\:$ wlog $\rm\,a > c.\,$  So it is $\rm\:100\,a+10\,b+c.\:$ Put $\rm\,d = a-c.\:$ Note $\rm\:0<d<10.$
$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} &&\rm 100\, a &+&\rm 10\, b &+&\rm c &&\\
                   -\ \ \  &&\rm 100\, c &+&\rm 10\, b &+&\rm a &&\\
\hline \\
                    =\ \  &&\rm 100\, d &&\rm &-&\rm d &&\rm 
\end{eqnarray}$$

In decimal, we have $\rm\ \ 100\,d\, -\, d\ =\ 100\ (\ d\,-\,1)\ +\ 90\ +\ (10-d),\:$ by borrowing. Thus

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&\rm 100(\ \ \ d\,-\,1) &+&\ \rm 90 &+&\rm \: (10-d) \\
+\ \ \ &&\rm 100(-d+10) &+&\ \rm 90 &+&\rm  (-1+d) \\
\hline \\
 =\ \ &&\rm 100\cdot 10 &+&\ \rm 80 &+&\rm \ 9 \end{eqnarray}$$

Note a carry into the hundreds digit $\: 100 + 80\, =\, 90 + 90.$

Comment: That seems more an answer than a hint =)!